# trigger io add default authorization header

Tags: trigger.io

Just wanted to understand what is the best way to add an Authorization header for all ajax requests using trigger io. Currently, I'm manually adding the header on each request. Would be great to know if such a feature is available or undocumented, and if not then what is the best way to do this. Something similar to AFNetworking which allows you to add persistent headers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't currently a way to set a default, you could write yourself a simple helper function though something like:

```
var username = "myuser";
var password = "skldjghslg";
function myAjax(options) {
    options.username = username;
    options.password = password;
    forge.request.ajax(options);
}
```

Then whenever you would normally use forge.request.ajax just use myAjax.